# cakephp 3 generating a config file from action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a registration form for domain owners and i want to create a config file for each usering on registering

I want to place these config files under `/config/domains/domainname.php`

Is there any component in CakePHP available which accepts data and can create a PHP file ?

Answer (score 0):

There is the Utility Classes for File and Folder.
 Have a look [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html).